# In MVC how can I return a IQueryable result and display it in a view using actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, mvvm, interface

net mvc and I would like to know how I can return and Iqueryable result and display it in a view using action result.

**This what my controller method currently looks like**

```
 private EmpEntities db = new EmpEntities();

        // GET: api/EmployeeInfoAPI
        public IQueryable<EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfoes()
        {
            return db.EmployeeInfoes;
        }
```

and this is what I am trying to achieve but I keep getting an error that says syntax error, '(' expected

```
public ActionResult IQueryable<EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfoes()
        {
            return View(db.EmployeeInfoes);
        }
```

I am not sure where I missing the bracket or if my methodology is just wrong

Answer (score 2):

type of result foraction "GetEmployeeInfoes" is ActionResult. use this syntax:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeInfoes()
{
     return View(db.EmployeeInfoes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a change in return statement "AsQueryable()".

```
public IQueryable<EmployeeInfo> GetEmployeeInfoes()
{
   return db.EmployeeInfoes.AsQueryable();
}
```